# Pearly White Spindle Ioun Stone

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Im confused as to the type of regeneration the Pearly White Spindle Ioun Stone provides.

Depending on the source I look at (I dont have my copy of the core rules with me) its text changes.

From [Nethys](http://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Ioun%20Stone%20Pearly%20White%20Spindle)

> Description Regenerate 1 point of damage per 10 minutes.

From [d20psrd](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/pearly-white-spindle-ioun-stone/)

> This stone grants the wearer the ability to regenerate 1 point of damage per 10 minutes. Regeneration works like a ring of regeneration. It only cures damage taken while the character is using the stone.

I seem to be getting conflicting information. Nethys only mentions that you gain a very slow regeneration, which implies that its the [universal monster ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Regeneration-Ex-) as there is no regeneration feat. There is the [regeneration spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/regenerate/) but it doesnt function the same way.

d20 however states that it works based off of the [ring of regeneration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-regeneration/) which is from the spell and not the monster ability. However d20 also links the regeneration word to the monster ability, but as we should all know by now, its an autolinking and d20 is not well known for their sites autolinking.

This is a very important distinction as what I am wanting is the universal monster ability regeneration (specifically its "but they cannot die as long as their regeneration is still functioning") instead of a glorified fast healing, which is also built into regeneration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magic item effects are routinely different from the effect of the spells listed in their construction requirements.

The regeneration from the spell is completely different from the regeneration granted by the ring, which works much more like the regeneration from the monster ability (healing over time).

This is of course insufficient to rule that the regeneration from the ring has the same advantage of not letting one die (that rule is often coupled with some kind of damage that does not regenerate, making the monster killable, while the ring has nothing like that), but it breaks your initial premise.

**Whether the ioun stone is based upon the ring or not is unimportant.**

What matters is if the ring provides monsterlike regeneration or just fast healing.

Since it's called regeneration, I'd look at what the regeneration quality does, even if I must admit it feels too powerful to be true and I would probably disallow it in my games.

Comment: Oh, its easy enough to kill PC's with regular regeneration, even co de graces can as their a death effect. Its not like the traskas which is even better.

Comment: It was also pointed out to me that the text is present, but located elsewhere while d20 had it merged into the item.